# Hazelcast losing connection to cloud node

Tags: java, azure, hazelcast

Hey I am running an Hazelcast node in Azure. I have ICMP enabled and am on the same private network as the cloud service in azure. I can connect to locally running Hazelcast nodes but when I give it the IP of the cloud node I get the following error. What could cause this? It Successfully connects and then immediately loses the connection. Is the heartbeat maybe not working? Are some timeouts to short?

```
09.08.2014 11:06:34 DEBUG (CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java:209) - [127.0.0.1]:5701 [noc-application-cluster] [3.3-RC4-SNAPSHOT] Successfully connected to: Address[10.101.1.11]:5701 using socket Socket[addr=/10.101.1.11,port=5701,localport=63975]
09.08.2014 11:06:34  INFO (SocketConnector.java:134) - [127.0.0.1]:5701 [noc-application-cluster] [3.3-RC4-SNAPSHOT] 63975 accepted socket connection from /10.101.1.11:5701
09.08.2014 11:06:34  INFO (AbstractSelectionHandler.java:60) - [127.0.0.1]:5701 [noc-application-cluster] [3.3-RC4-SNAPSHOT] Connection [Address[10.101.1.11]:5701] lost. Reason: java.io.EOFException[Remote socket closed!]
09.08.2014 11:06:34 DEBUG (TcpIpConnection.java:228) - [127.0.0.1]:5701 [noc-application-cluster] [3.3-RC4-SNAPSHOT] Destroying Connection [/10.101.1.11:5701 -> Address[10.101.1.11]:5701] live=false, client=false, type=MEMBER
```

On the cloud node I'm seeing the following:

```
09.08.2014 15:11:35  INFO (Thread.java:745) - [127.0.0.1]:5701 [noc-qa] [3.3-RC4-SNAPSHOT] Accepting socket connection from /10.200.1.168:64089
09.08.2014 15:11:35  INFO (SocketAcceptor.java:144) - [127.0.0.1]:5701 [noc-qa] [3.3-RC4-SNAPSHOT] 5701 accepted socket connection from /10.200.1.168:64089
09.08.2014 15:11:35  WARN (BindOperation.java:48) - [127.0.0.1]:5701 [noc-qa] [3.3-RC4-SNAPSHOT] Wrong bind request from Address[127.0.0.1]:5701! This node is not requested endpoint: Address[10.101.1.11]:5701
09.08.2014 15:11:35  INFO (TcpIpConnectionManager.java:218) - [127.0.0.1]:5701 [noc-qa] [3.3-RC4-SNAPSHOT] Connection [/10.200.1.168:64089] lost. Reason: Socket explicitly closed
```

Hazelcast Code that's producing the WARN message:

```
final Address thisAddress = ioService.getThisAddress();
if (!connection.isClient() && !thisAddress.equals(localEndpoint)) {
   log(Level.WARNING, "Wrong bind request from " + remoteEndPoint
                    + "! This node is not requested endpoint: " + localEndpoint);
    connection.close();
    return false;
 }
```

Why would node A receive a join request from node B which is obviously trying to connect with node A and then node A decides that the request wasnt meant for it? Does the Azure node always think it's 127.0.0.1? Is it not aware of its private IP?

Comment: what's the ICMP timeout/ttl (or are you using the default)?  Also, have you tried testing with heartbeats instead instead of icmp?

Comment: Oh i didn't realize that ICMP and heartbeat were two separate options. I have ICMP enabled in Azure, which is I thought what I needed to do to enable heartbeats in Hazelcast. But in hazelcast i have heartbeat enabled and ICMP disabled. The problem with the above is that the current node doesn't think a certain request is meant for it. This might be an azure specific issue. I have updated my question with the hazelcast code that's producing the WARN.

Comment: @bjoenr - is tcp-ip enabled in the config (or are you using multicasting) - if tcp is being used, can you share what you have in the interfaces section?  it may be related to the fact that the default value of 'hazelcast.socket.bind.any' used to be set to true (have to check again). So you might want to confirm if you have the right ip address in the hazelcast config section for tcp (use tcp as opposed to multicasting - might be better route).

Comment: I actually wrote an azure based config implementation and am bundling it with the Hazelcast jar. But underlying it uses tcp-ip. All it does is it makes a REST call to the Azure management api and gets the list of private ip addresses for a given service name. I'm confident that's not the issue, all my tests are fine. It's just when one of the nodes in azure gets a request it doesn't think it's meant for it.

Comment: perhaps its getting the DNS name when its expecting the ip address?  you could try patching hazelcast with additional comments if its not there already and confirm that

Comment: also, have you tried the google group for hazelcast?  I'm interested in in finding out myself

Comment: I added an issue on github about it https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/3243

Comment: seems like hazelcast dev is saying more or less the same (DNS/ip or local/external IP)